# Show Info of All Use Accounts

Tags: windows, command-line, user-accounts

I can find and one by one show the info of users using the command:

```
net users
```

but is there any way I can view the Info of all users at once?
Such as a:

```
net users /all
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Well there is no one OS. I need to execute this on Windows XP to 7 machines and Windows Server 2003 to 2008 machines. Thats the best range I can give you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wmic useraccount list /format:list
```

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows XP Home Edition (tested it myself; however it seems to be available on all other platforms ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation#WMI_tools)).

Comment: On Windows 10, this command never completes. It just hangs there and does not return an answer.

Comment: @KAE it works for me on Windows 10, see [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/yYjQk)

Comment: It just took a very long time (5+ minutes), so my earlier comment was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like this:

[image: User Accounts]

On **Run**, type:

```
control userpasswords2
```

And you can see graphically all users and by selecting Properties, you can then see some of their attributes.

Based roughly on this [source](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windowsxp/ht/auto-logon-xp.htm) and [this](http://www.mcmcse.com/microsoft/guides/manage_users.shtml) for some pictures. It is somewhat of an obscure command, though. And it works on XP, so I can't say for sure it works on versions upper than that.

Comment: Works on Win7. Cliff

Comment: I want to do this from the command line.

Comment: In that case, you could write a batch file, but I've been looking at that and, since the output of `>net user` isn't easy to treat, this would seem like the best option, unless you weren't opposed to something in the likes of a Python script.